# Get attached videos for a page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, video

How do I retrieve a PHP object for a video that I added to a page in wordpress.

```
$images = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
//returns all images I uploaded in the editor
```

This works fine for images but won't work for videos

```
$videos = get_attached_media('video', $post->ID);
//returns an empty array
```

Comment: Are you sure that page is having a video attachment?

Comment: I added one using the "add media" button and updated the page

Comment: Can you please edit the page and see if media is actually added to the page.

Comment: If I change the template from my custom one where I try to retrieve the attachments to a standard template the video is being displayed

Comment: Maybe your template has a function that overwrites the behavior of the `video` media type? Can you share the template's `functions.php` code?

Comment: Have you tried using wp_get_attachment_url() function?

Comment: The only line in functions.php that contains the word video is the following:    add_theme_support('post-formats', array('aside', 'image', 'video', 'quote', 'link'));

Comment: To check if there is a 'video' post format assigned to the post, use

// in your theme single.php, page.php or custom post type
if ( has_post_format( 'video' ) ) {
 echo 'This is a video.';
}    and see if actually support is added.

Comment: the_content() adds images and videos to the page while has_post_format('video') is false